# Memory leaks? in passing IEnumerable<byte[]> array to unmanaged function as byte** parameter

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, interop, unmanaged, managed

Is that the correct way to allocate and free handles to managed data passed to unmanaged dll?

There is unmanaged dll with exported function

```
void Function(byte** ppData, int N);
```

I need to pass it `IEnumerable<byte[]> afids`

```
var handles = afids.Select(afid => GCHandle.Alloc(afid, GCHandleType.Pinned));
var ptrs = handles.Select(h => h.AddrOfPinnedObject());
IntPtr[] afidPtrs = ptrs.ToArray();
uint N = (uint)afidPtrs.Length;

Function(afidPtrs, N);

handles.ToList().ForEach(h => h.Free());
```

I get managed memory leaks and getting sos.dll in Immediate Window gave gcroot

```
DOMAIN(00275030):HANDLE(Pinned):3ea2c0:Root:  17a8d190(System.Byte[])
```

Function definition is:

```
[DllImport("My.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern unsafe internal int Function(IntPtr[] ppData, int N);
```

Buggy code snippet for console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        IEnumerable<byte[]> data = CreateEnumeration(100);
        PinEntries(data);
        Thread.Sleep(900);
        Console.Write(String.Format("gc mem: {0}\r", GC.GetTotalMemory(true)));
    }
}

static IEnumerable<byte[]> CreateEnumeration(int size)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    IList<byte[]> data = new List<byte[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        byte[] vector = new byte[12345];
        random.NextBytes(vector);
        data.Add(vector);
    }
    return data;
}

static void PinEntries(IEnumerable<byte[]> data)
{
    var handles = data.Select(d => GCHandle.Alloc(d, GCHandleType.Pinned));
    var ptrs = handles.Select(h => h.AddrOfPinnedObject());
    IntPtr[] dataPtrs = ptrs.ToArray();
    Thread.Sleep(100); // unmanaged function call taking byte** data
    handles.ToList().ForEach(h => h.Free());
}
```

Correct code snippet for console application:

```
static void PinEntries(IEnumerable<byte[]> data)
{
    IEnumerable<GCHandle> handles = CreateHandles(data);
    IntPtr[] ptrs = GetAddrOfPinnedObjects(handles);
    Thread.Sleep(100); // unmanaged function call taking byte** data
    FreeHandles(handles);
}

static IEnumerable<GCHandle> CreateHandles(IEnumerable<byte[]> data)
{
    IList<GCHandle> handles = new List<GCHandle>();
    foreach (byte[] vector in data)
    {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(vector, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            handles.Add(handle);
    }
    return handles;
}

static IntPtr[] GetAddrOfPinnedObjects(IEnumerable<GCHandle> handles)
{
    IntPtr[] ptrs = new IntPtr[handles.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ptrs.Length; i++)
            ptrs[i] = handles.ElementAt(i).AddrOfPinnedObject();
    return ptrs;
}

static void FreeHandles(IEnumerable<GCHandle> handles)
{
    foreach (GCHandle handle in handles)
            handle.Free();
}
```

Comment: Can you show how do you define Function for interop in C#?

Comment: ok, have added. there are no problems in reading the data in unmanaged code, nor any leaks in unmanaged dll verified in debug build with `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`

Comment: try specifying manually static extern unsafe internal int Function([MarshalAs(LPArray,ArraySubType=U4)]IntPtr[] ppData, int N); (for 32bit code)

Comment: there are no problems with unmanaged function call. 

the dll and exe are explicitly compiled as 32 bit.

if you run the attached code snippet the mem leak increases in any case. it is the pinned handle which is not released somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void PinEntries(IEnumerable<byte[]> data)
{
    var handles = data.Select(d => GCHandle.Alloc(d, GCHandleType.Pinned));
    var ptrs = handles.Select(h => h.AddrOfPinnedObject());
    IntPtr[] dataPtrs = ptrs.ToArray();
    Thread.Sleep(100); // unmanaged function call taking byte** data
    handles.ToList().ForEach(h => h.Free());
}
```

You are falling into a Linq trap, its enumerators don't behave like a collection.  The handles get allocated *twice*, first when you use ptrs.ToArray(), again when you use handles.ToList().  With the obvious side-effect that the first set of handles don't get freed.  Fix:

```
        var handles = data.Select(d => GCHandle.Alloc(d, GCHandleType.Pinned)).ToList();
        var ptrs = handles.Select(h => h.AddrOfPinnedObject());
        IntPtr[] dataPtrs = ptrs.ToArray();
        handles.ForEach(h => h.Free());
```

Note the added ToList() to force the enumeration into a collection.

Comment: My compliments on the repro code btw, you made it easy to help you.

Comment: thank you very much, just before I saw your answer I had modified my snippet by removing all LINQ stuff and the problem had been resolved

Comment: I was inspired by LINQ code brevity which led me into the GCHandle trap. As I've seen from articles that is the very efficient way to leak in .NET application :)